# How to Save relation table data using EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

```
 [DataContract]
   public class Commodity
    {
       [DataMember]
        [Key]
        public long ID { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       [DataType(DataType.Text)]
       [StringLength(40)]
       public string Name { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public virtual List<DailyPrice> ComodityDailyPrices { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
     public virtual List<DailyProduction> CommodityDailyProduction { get;set; }

    }

//==========================//

 [DataContract]
  public class Currency
  {
    [DataMember]
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<DailyPrice> DailyPrices { get; set; }

  }

 //==========================//

 [DataContract]
  public class DailyPrice
  {
    [DataMember]
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public long CommodityID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    //[ForeignKey("CommodityID")]
    public virtual Commodity commodity { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public long CurrencyID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Currency currency { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public double Price { get; set; }
}

 //==========================//

 public bool create(DailyPrice _create)
    {
        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
            context.DailyPrices.Add(_create);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

//there is a relation between currencies ,commodities and daily-prices.So        While saving Dailyprice the curriences and commodotes also get repeated values   like
 For Commodites
  1     Oil
  2     Gas
  3     Water
  4    Water.

For Currencies

1   INR
2   USD
3   EURO
4   SDG
9   EURO

Please let me known where i am doing sumthing wrong.

Comment: can you make your question more clear? are you getting problem as the data is getting repeated in the tables or you want to add the data to the tables currencies and commodities? if the first part is the issue, the code you provided not enough to let us to find where is the problem

Comment: Thanks for ur rply.13 12 9 01-MAR-01 9000.0

Comment: Thanks for ur rply Hassan. Problem is as the data is getting repeated in their tables currencies and commodities while saving dailyprices. where daily prices table just saving the refrences of  currencies and commodities . Like ID-1 CommodityID-12 CurrencyID-9 Date-01-MAR-01 Price-9000.0

Comment: put the code responsible on filling the _create object, it seems EF doesn't know for some reason not able to know that Currency object inside the DialyPrice is an existing one and it should be referenced and not created and then referenced

Comment: public bool create(DailyPrice _create)
            {
                 using (var context = new DbContext())
                   {
                   context.DailyPrices.Add(_create);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return true;
                }
           }

Comment: modify your code, and add the _create object initialization, how you are filling it and not after passing it to the function create